# Run multiple T-test and correct for multiple comparisons

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, adjustment

I have tried to look for a quick way to solve this questions but I have found no complete solution so I decided to post the question.

I have a dataset about the rate of heat gain on four types of fiddler crabs. The fiddler crabs have a huge claw which is supposed to promote heat sink. Since we want to compare the mean between four groups we should go for an ANOVA, if the assumptions are met, or the Kruskal-Wallis test otherwise.

I wanted to do multiple t-test or  and then correct for multiple comparisons using FDR, Bonferroni or other method.
David proposed a way to conduct multiple t-test to compare differences between groups ([Web-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794209/apply-function-stat-test-to-subsets-of-data-for-each-factor-level)).

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=rep(c("a","a","b","b"),3), v2=c(rep("x",4),rep("y",4),rep("z",4)), dv=sample(1:100, 12), id=rep(c("p1","p2"),6))

split_dat <- split(dat, dat$v2)

sapply(split_dat, function(sub_dat) {
result <- t.test(sub_dat[sub_dat$v1 == "a", "dv"],
               sub_dat[sub_dat$v1 == "b", "dv"])

return(result$p.value)
})
```

My goal is to run the multiple t-test or Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test or a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test between groups according to a factor (crabType), and lastly run a correction for multiple comparisons to get only those p-values than are statistical significant after correction.

The dataset is

```
http://whitlockschluter.zoology.ubc.ca/wp-content/data/chapter15/chap15q30FiddlerCrabFans.csv
```

Comment: There is no need to run an ANOVA as long as you control the Type I error as you plan to do. The Tukey hsd is a bit more powerful than a Bonferroni correction since the former is based on correlations among comparisons whereas the latter assumes the worst (independence).